# Simple Navigation Routing Error in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

longtime reader & first time poster, so I'd appreciate it if you went easy on me.

Recently started teaching myself RoR, and have been hacking away at a personal project/website to get the hang of things.  Here's my problem:

**I'm using the Simple Navigation gem to generate links.  Inside navigation.rb I'm trying to call:**

```
primary.item :home, 'Home', home_path
```

...where home is a view and controller that displays my front page:

1. home > index.html.erb (just contains a bunch of standard HTML, but let me know if it'd be useful to include)
2. and controllers > home_controller.rb:

> ```
> class HomeController < ApplicationController
>   def index
>     @posts = Post.all
>   end
> end
> ```

I'm getting this error, though:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"home"}
>
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

... so I run rake routes, and can definitely see "home#show" in there.

My routes.rb file, as well, has this in it:

```
  get "projects/index"
  get "offer/index"
  get "space/index"
  get "home/index"

  resources :posts
  resources :home
```

So I'm a little baffled, and I'm sure it's because of my inexperience or general inability to understand what I'm doing, but I'd really appreciate some help as it's more or less a road block that I haven't been able to overcome.

Appreciate it!

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the resources; if you are not using the resources remove **resources :home**

This could be your routes:

```
  get "projects/index"
  get "offer/index"
  get "space/index"
  get "home/index", :as => "home"

  resources :posts
```

See how I removed the **resources :home**. In home/index the **:as** represents an alias, so you can use the alias as a method, adding "path" at the end of the name.

Check this guide about routes and resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default